# Check ownership of record in public CloudKit database

Tags: ios, cloudkit, apple-id

I've just began working with CloudKit and planning to store data in a public CloudKit database. One feature I need is to display information about who has created a record and also let that owner to modify or delete their own records.

None of the tutorials I've read so far talk about this.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get that from the CKRecord like this:

```
record.recordID
record.recordType
record.creationDate
record.creatorUserRecordID
record.modificationDate
record.lastModifiedUserRecordID
record.recordChangeTag
```

The rights for the user (public, authenticated, owner) who can create / update / delete a record can be setup in the CloudKit dashboard

Comment: Thank you. And I assume I can compare the creatorUserRecordId with a logged in user to see if the users owns a record and adapt the UI?

Comment: yes, you can. You can use the container.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler to get the current user.